Sanity HTML Content Not Rendering Properly in Next.js with Tailwind CSS
We're utilizing Sanity, Next.js, and Tailwind CSS in our project. I've added a field named 'raw_html' in Sanity, which contains some HTML content along with sample data
<div class="p-4 bg-gray-100 rounded-lg">
  <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold mb-4">Hello World</h1>
  <p class="mb-2">This is a paragraph with <span class="text-blue-500">Tailwind CSS</span> classes.</p>
  <ul class="list-disc ml-5">
    <li class="mb-1">First item</li>
    <li class="mb-1">Second item</li>
    <li class="mb-1">Third item</li>
  </ul>
</div>

However, this content isn't displaying correctly on the frontend. When I embed the HTML directly into the code, it appears fine. Could there be a specific reason for this issue or a potential solution? Thanks in advance.
Here is the code
import { useSite } from '@/app/contexts/SiteContext'; // Ensure the correct import
function Header() {
    const site = useSite();
    if (!site) return <div>Loading...</div>;
    return (
        <div className="m-10">
            <div className="text-center text-red-500">Tailwind CSS is working!</div>
            <div className="prose max-w-none" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: site.header.templateDetails.raw_html }} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Header;


What type of field is raw_html? type: 'text'?

My guess is that the HTML is pulling in just fine, but some (or all) of those classes are not being included in the CSS file generated by Tailwind because the code in Sanity is being added dynamically (after the Tailwind purge). For example, if "text-3xl" doesn't exist somewhere in your source files, your tailwind CSS file will not have a definition for it. See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

@kylepg Yes, It's  type: 'text'

@kylepg I can see the exact HTML in view-source: https://www.screenpresso.com/=CUeMc

@kylepg I expect it should be like https://play.tailwindcss.com/WgMl9KHld0

Yeah those classes in your HTML aren't actually doing anything because they're not defined in the stylesheet. Those classes need to be present in your source code in order for Tailwind to know to include them in the build process. It looks correct on play.tailwindcss.com because they have a script injecting all the class definitions dynamically. You can mimic that behavior by including <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script> somewhere on your site, however that isn't recommended for production

You could also add those classes manually to a safelist to ensure they're included, but you'd need to do that every time you introduce a new class into Sanity which likely isn't feasible. See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes

You can use the plugin react-portable-text and then use it instead of setting the innerhtml element in below given way:
<PortableText 
      content={site.header.templateDetails.raw_html} 
      serializers={{ 
        div: ({ children }) => <div className="p-4 bg-gray-100 rounded-lg">{children}</div>,
        h1: ({ children }) => <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold mb-4">{children}</h1>,
        p: ({ children }) => <p className="mb-2">{children}</p>,
        ul: ({ children }) => <ul className="list-disc ml-5">{children}</ul>,
        li: ({ children }) => <li className="mb-1">{children}</li>,
        someCustomType: YourComponent,
      }}
    />

Also, make sure that tailwindcss is implemented successfully in your project.
